# Using LINQ to XML to Parse a SOAP message

Tags: c#, soap, linq-to-xml

I am getting up to speed in Linq to XML in C# and attempting to parse the following message and don't seem to be making much progress. Here is the soap message I am not sure if I perhaps I need to use a namespace. Here is the SOAP message I am trying to format. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am attempting to extract the values. Thanks.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Body>
  <Lookup xmlns="http://ASR-RT/">
   <objIn>
    <transactionHeaderData>
     <intWebsiteId>1000</intWebsiteId>
     <strVendorData>test</strVendorData>
     <strVendorId>I07</strVendorId>
    </transactionHeaderData>
    <intCCN>17090769</intCCN>
    <strSurveyResponseFlag>Y</strSurveyResponseFlag>
   </objIn>
  </CCNLookup>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you post the code you do have?  Or at least an example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Any particular reason for manually parsing SOAP messages?

Answer (score 9):

If this is about interacting with a SOAP service please use
[Add Service Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386382.aspx) or [wsdl.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28VS.80%29.aspx).

If this is just about parsing the XML, assuming you've got the SOAP response into an XDocument named soapDocument:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://ASR-RT/";
var objIns = 
    from objIn in soapDocument.Descendants(ns + "objIn")
    let header = objIn.Element(ns + "transactionHeaderData")
    select new
    {
        WebsiteId = (int) header.Element(ns + "intWebsiteId"),
        VendorData = header.Element(ns + "strVendorData").Value,
        VendorId = header.Element(ns + "strVendorId").Value,
        CCN = (int) objIn.Element(ns + "intCCN"),
        SurveyResponse = objIn.Element(ns + "strSurveyResponseFlag").Value,
    };
```

That will give you an IEnumerable of [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) you deal with as fully strongly typed objects within that method.

Comment: Thank you very much cameron, your answer helped me a lot i solved issue after a day search

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq's XDocument to load the XML text by calling `XDocument.Load()` or similar.  Then you can walk through the tree of elements off the xdoc's Root, using functions like

```
foreach (var x in xdoc.Elements("Lookup"))
{...}
```

Comment: I believe he needs xdoc.Elements(XName.Get("lookup", "http://ASR-RT/")) as the Xml has a default namespace

Answer (score 0):

You can get your XML into an XElement an then just do:

```
rsp.Descendants("Lookup").ToList();
```

Or

rsp.Descendants("objIn").ToList();

I think this is the best way to do it. I think that XElement is the best choice.