# Specific value with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a xml file and I want to extract some data from it.

I have this linq query and I get the details in the var but I cant reach the values.

```
XNamespace aw1 = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/FAQ/";
var r03 = from el in obj.Descendants().Elements(aw1 + "co")
                                select el.Elements(aw1 + "doc");
```

I've tried using a loop but I get a casting error and I think there is a straight way to get the values, I'm trying to avoid the loop because we I always know the structure and it's not necessary to parse the entire file and just get what I'm looking for.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Header>
    <wsse:Security S:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.org/wss/2004/secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.org/utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsu:Created>2016-01-28T21:54:57Z</wsu:Created>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
  </S:Header>
  <S:Body>
    <ConsultarEdocumentResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.stackoverflow.com/" xmlns="http://www.stackoverflow.com/FAQ/">
      <response>
        <mensaje>No Message</mensaje>
        <resultadoBusqueda>
          <co>
            <doc>151AQP</doc>
            <patentes>
              <patente>1111</patente>
            </patentes>
            <facturas>
              <factura>
              <subdivision>0</subdivision>
              <mercancias>
                <mercancia>
                  <desc>ACCESORIO</desc>
                  <cantidad>189000</cantidad>
                </mercancia>
                <mercancia>
                  <desc>ACCESORIO A</desc>
                  <cantidad>9000</cantidad>
                </mercancia>
              </mercancias>
              </factura>
            </facturas>
            <emisor>
              <tipoIdentificador>0</tipoIdentificador>
              <domicilio>
                <calle>STREET</calle>
                <codigoPostal>55555</codigoPostal>
              </domicilio>
            </emisor>
            <destinatario>
              <tipoIdentificador>1</tipoIdentificador>
              <domicilio>
                <calle>Street</calle>
                <codigoPostal>65555</codigoPostal>
              </domicilio>
            </destinatario>
          </co>
        </resultadoBusqueda>
      </response>
    </ConsultarEdocumentResponse>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Please help me with this, I've been trying several things but I feel that I'm not getting anything usefull. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve] - ideally with a shorter XML file, too.

Comment: Are you saying you want a list of the values in the doc elements?  So for the example xml you want the single value 151AQP?

Comment: I gave this a go, and can't remember query with XDocument being so difficult. Really bad API in my opinion.

Comment: I want to get the specific value in the 151AQP, and more values in this same level and other levels.

Answer (score 1):

LinqToXML is really great library, but SOAP is so bad that its badness goes to LinqToXML too. Looks like you mixed some XML namespaces:

```
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        XNamespace soapNs = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
        XNamespace soNs = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/FAQ/";

        var docList = xdoc.Root.Descendants(soapNs + "Body")
            .Descendants(soNs + "co")
            .Descendants(soNs + "doc")
            .ToList();

        docList.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Value));
```

For more info check this SO question: [Using LINQ to XML to Parse a SOAP message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329825/using-linq-to-xml-to-parse-a-soap-message)

Comment: Correct Implementation Approch

Comment: Thank you for you help @csharpfolk, the namespaces just came that way, I changed the second just for privacy, I can get the desired value using you query (tag doc), I understand that I can do the same in other querys to get other values, but it's possible to get them all in the same query?

Comment: I've been playing around with your query and I can get more values in one query, but I'm not been able to get values from other levels, this is what i have so far.

Comment: var data = from el in doc.Root.Descendants(aw2 + "Body")
                                .Descendants(aw1 + "co")
                                select new 
                                {
                                    doc = el.Element(aw1 + "doc").Value
                                    , no = el.Element(aw1 + "no").Value
                                    , ex = el.Element(aw1 + "ex").Value
                                };

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, I'm still new to this great community.

Comment: Hi guys, this is what I'm using finally, it can get values from several levels and this is the way I'm getting the values too.

Comment: <!-- language: c# -->
var d = from el in doc.Root.Descendants(aw2 + "Body")
                                .Descendants(aw1 + "co")
                            let merc=doc.Root.Descendants(aw2 + "Body").Descendants(aw1 + "co").Descendants(aw1 + "facturas").Descendants(aw1 + "mercancias")
                                select new 
                                {
                                    doc=el.Element(aw1+"doc").Value
                                    , mercancias= mercancias.Elements(aw1+"mercancia").ToList()};